# How should I use WebElements and Actions through page object model?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, action, pageobjects, webdriverwait

I have a button on my Webpage which I want to click once the required piece of information is entered. I am currently using By to establish all the elements of the page but want to use WebElements for this button and then use Actions to click it later.
How should I do that in my Page Object class.

I tried with below approach :

```
WebElement addressinput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='pac-input']"));
By addressinput = By.xpath("//input[@id='pac-input']");//this works fine
```

But on running the Test class as TestNG it shows null pointer exception on WebElement line. Tried to do it with By as well but the button just won't recieve the click. It works pefectly fine with WebElements and action which I have tried before without using POM below is the reference code for that :

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='btn_gtservice']"));  
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement((WebElement) CheckAvailability).click().perform();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: @Kovind - Did you find a solution for this? I recently stumbled upon the same issue that you are facing?

Comment: I think my reference to WebElement was incorrect as pointed out by Jsmith200 in the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got

`action.moveToElement((WebElement)CheckAvailability)`

That should be

`action.moveToElement((button)CheckAvailability)`

As it is, you'll be getting a null pointer as you have no variable named WebElement defined

Answer (score 0):

When using **PageFactory** in **PageObjectModel** if you expect the element to be loaded after some information is entered, through some [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) and it might not be immediately present on the page already you can use the *Actions* once the element is returned through *WebDriverWait* support with a normal locator factory as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  package com.pol.zoho.PageObjects;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
  import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

  public class ZohoLoginPage {

      WebDriver driver;
      public ZohoLoginPage(WebDriver driver)
      {
          PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
      }

      @FindBy(xpath="//button[@id='btn_gtservice']")
      public WebElement myButton;

      public void doLogin(String username,String userpassword)
      {
          WebElement button = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ZohoLoginPage.getWebElement()));
          new Actions(driver).moveToElement(button).click().perform();
      }

      public WebElement getWebElement()
      {
          return myButton;
      }

  }
  ```

You can find a detailed discussion in [How to use explicit waits with PageFactory fields and the PageObject pattern](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/7AGczMaV578)